# Error creating a window in windows "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, codeblocks, winmain

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int     nCmdShow)
{

const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

WNDCLASS wc = { };

wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

RegisterClass(&wc);



HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    CLASS_NAME,
    L"Learn to Program Windows",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,


    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
    );

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);



MSG msg = { };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return 0;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;

case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This is the code, which is also the standard example you can find in the microsoft website that teach people how to program windows.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem I receive is the following whenever I try to compile this code in codeblocks.

undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

What is that and what can I do to compile and run this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange to me that `WinMain` is called `wWinMain`: evidently you need a function called `WinMain`.

Oh, wait, you are using codeblocks? Probably `wWinMain` is specific of visual studio. Codeblocks wants the standard `WinMain`.

Comment: Yep that was it. By changing it from

    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

to 

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

Thank you :)

Comment: È il problema microsoft: gli standard.

Comment: Come fai a sapere che io sia italiano? O.O
Comunque non posso votarti la risposta perchè mi mancano 2di reputazione per votare. Grazie comunque però :)